# Homestead - Pass Project URL to Virtual Machine

Tags: laravel, internet-explorer, virtual-machine, homestead

I am currently working with on a Laravel project running on Homestead on a Mac, and I am attempting to test the project in a [Internet Explorer VM](http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/04/internet-explorer-for-mac-ie7-ie8-ie-9-free/).

I do not know how to reach the local URL of my Homestead instance via the VM, is there a simple way to achieve this?

EDIT:

I have attempted to change the hosts file on my VM box to:

`192.168.0.53 chealth.dev`

Which is my machines IP address proceeded by the homestead URL.

Answer (score 0):

Add the IP of your local machine (MAC) in the hosts file of the Internet Explorer VM,

```
ip.of.the.mac project.url
```

Make sure the hostname is the same as defined in the Homestead.yaml file. 
Then you can reach the site on the Internet explorer VM using: `project.url:8000` (assuming you haven't changed the port in homestead).

Comment: Can you post the relevant section of the hosts file of the VM?

Comment: Try switching the network mode on the box to bridged.

Comment: That didn't do it either